# Magento Left Side Menu On Cart Page (Display Previously Removed Sidebar Block)

Tags: cart, layout, menu

I have menu on left side area. When product is add to cart it will redirect me to the cart page. On cart page the menu is not shown. I have added `$this->getChildHtml('left');` into the `1column.phtml` as it is showing on all page but on cart page but it is still not showing.

How can I add the menu to the left side of the cart page?

Comment: Have you added the relevant block (containing the menu) to the `left` block in the layout for the cart page?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 3column layout and in config file for cart action add that block under left section, you can write left section as you defined for left side menu. In one column, it does not provide left or right section.

Comment: thanks i got another solution on Checkout.xml it is mention <remove name="left"/> hide it side area will come.